# Front End Data Verification in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am running data driven framework (TestNG) 
i want to compare a excel cell value with a pre selected value in drop down menu

This is the Drop Down menu HTML code

```
select id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlCalculation"class="normalText"  
style="width:100%;" 
onchange="javascript:LoadMethods(this.value);CallonChange(this.value,'spn_ddlCalculation');return false;" disabled="disabled" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCalculation"

<option value="0" selected="selected">--- Select ---</option>

<option value="f">Formula Based</option>

<option value="m">Formula Based with Matrix Table</option>

<option value="q">Quantity Based</option>

<option value="t">Time Based</option>

</select>
```

this is Selenium Code which i have written

```
WebElement DDmenu = driver.findElement(By.id(WebelementID));

String Content = TxtBoxContent.getAttribute("Option");

String ExcelData = Generic.getXlCellValue(xlpath, sheetName, rownum, cellnum);

if (Content.equals(ExcelData))

{

Reporter.log(LocationName+" Data Verification -- PASS",true);

}

else

{

Assert.fail(LocationName+"Data Verification -- Failed");

}
```

it is failing to compare please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Select select = new Select(DDmenu);
>
> WebElement option= select.getFirstSelectedOption();
>
> String Content=option.getText();
>
> String ExcelData = Generic.getXlCellValue(xlpath, sheetName, rownum,
>   cellnum);
>
> if (Content.equals(ExcelData))
>
> {
>
> Reporter.log(LocationName+" Data Verification -- PASS",true);
>
> }
>
> else
>
> {
>
> Assert.fail(LocationName+"Data Verification -- Failed");
>
> }